# Remove extra folder from Android Project View in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have the library and 2 samples for it. Say `my-sdk`, `sample1`, `sample2`. The file structure is:

Project folder, inside it `settings.gradle`, `my-sdk` and `samples` folder. Inside `samples` I have `sample1` and `sample2` folders.

My `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':my-sdk', 'samples:sample1', 'samples:sample2'
```

The problem is:
In Android Project View I see 4 projects:

- sample1
- sample2
- my-sdk
- samples (empty)

How to remove `samples` folder from Android Project View?

BTW. I have file `samples.iml` inside `samples` folder. So looks like for me that Android Studio thinks thats `samples` is a module but it just a folder for other modules.

**UPD** If I try to remove this empty module from `Module Settings F4` than IDE crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Do these steps:

- remove from the `sample` folder the `.iml` file
- remove from the `sample` folder the `build.gradle` (if it exists)
- run a `./gradlew clean` and resync gradle project.

If it is not enough remove:

- **.idea** : in this folder Android Studio saves the settings
- **.iml** in each module. In these files Android Studio stores the module information

Delete these resources, and then reimport again the folder.

Comment: This is good, but maybe exist any way that this folder foes not appears after import project? I don't wont that users which use my library see this folder.

Comment: It is a physical folder and it exists... The user will see it if he uses the "Project" view as he displays the .idea or .gradle folder.

Comment: yes, but I talk only about  Android Project View. I have a loot of subfolders in my root folder, but they don't appears it Android Project View.

Comment: @anber As I know, it depends by the filter used in this view and it is different for any clients. It doesn't depend by gradle or project config,